# codeigniter active record using like,or,match in the same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have been stuck in this phase for an hour.

My purpose is to make a search using table `tag_name`, if in `tag_name` give no_result I want using product name table with like condition.Or I can get result from both condition above.

Thanks for all kindness here:

```
function search_products($searchStr)
{ 
    $this->db->select('a.*, b.,c.*,c.id as id_product',FALSE); 
    $this->db->from('tags_events a ',FALSE); 
    $this->db->join('products b','a.product_id = b.id ',FALSE); 
    $this->db->join('products_details c', 'b.id = c.product_id', 'left'); 
    $this->db->where("MATCH (tag_name) AGAINST ('{$searchStr}')OR b.product_name LIKE '%$searchStr%' ", NULL, FALSE); 
    $this->db->group_by("b.product_name"); 
    $query=$this->db->get(); 
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Please format correctly.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem will be solve if you use mysql **Pattern Matching**

*MySQL provides standard SQL pattern matching as well as a form of pattern matching based on extended regular expressions similar to those used by Unix utilities such as vi, grep, and sed.*

if you needing explain be detail, you can visit this link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html